# Retriving the data of the Google+ Comment Widget?

Tags: facebook, comments, google-plus

I have 2 articles I'm going to merge into a new one. Each one has the Facebook and G+ comment widgets.

With the Graph API, I can get the FB comments of both articles, inserting to DB and assigning them to the new article.
But I can't find a way of merging the Google comments.

Is there an API that allow me to do the same as FB?

Thank you

PS: Also, is there a way of merging FB likes and Google +1?

Comment: The best you can do to get Google+ comment widget data is using the [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) API with the URL the comments were posted under. What do you mean by merging likes and +1's?

Comment: abraham, I tried it but I only get the shares of other people related with a URL but no the one's in the comment widget :( 
Thank you anyway.

About the likes and +1, I want the sum of likes of every page count for the new article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is mostly no. You can get comments with [activities.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) but it will only return comments that have been publicly shared to Google+. Comments not shared to Google+ or shared to a circle on Google+ are not available through the search API.

Merging Facebook likes and Google +1's is as simple as taking the two numbers and adding them together. The difficult part is getting the numbers. Facebook has an [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/url) that returns the number of likes but Google+ does not. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=57) you can star.